# Does anyone have any solutions for playing an ASF stream in an iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, windows, streaming, asf

As a part of my app I'm building, I'm trying to add a radio feed, and the radio station in question only supplies an asx/asf stream and has no plans to support anything else, so I have no access to change any of the source stream.

Obviously, reading an ASF stream using the default libraries does not work, as the iPhone does not support asf streams naively. However, there are a couple of apps out there that do this, for example FStream: http://www.sourcemac.com/?page=fstream

So, does anyone have any idea how this is done?

The other option is getting a server and re-streaming the feed as mp3. We have a dedicated windows server, and this option has been working for us using VLC, except VLC has issues on windows and stops itself after a few days.

So my question is twofold:

1. Does anyone know of any code out there that allows me to play an ASF stream in my iPhone app?
2. Does anyone have any better suggestions for a windows application to restream the ASF to mp3 that won't just up and die after a period of time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using VLC on a linux machine like ubuntu? Ubuntu linux and apps seem to be more stable than windows.

Comment: We're currently trying that, but the feed still stopped after approximately 100 hours. If it happens again, we're out of alternatives.

Comment: running a script to stop and restart it once a day, and it seems to have helped with the stopping problem. So I guess Linux VLC was our solution after all.